# How customize link generated by git after git push --set-upstream

Tags: git, github, pull-request

after pushing the changes for the first time to Github with
`git push --set-upstream ...`
git create a pull request URL for us like
`https://github.com/username/hello-world/pull/new/task`
so my question is can we customize this URL, for example, adding a title like `https://github.com/username/hello-world/pull/new/task?title=new+PR`

Answer (score 2):

Git doesn’t generate this URL, GitHub replies to your push with some text that is displayed in the terminal that happens to include a URL that their server generates. GitHub does not provide a means to change this text including the URL.